# WinRT Custom Virtualizing Panel

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

as the list of bugs and limitations whith every standard virtualizing panel in WinRT is getting longer and more annoying for me, I need to write my own virtualizing panel which fit's all my needs.

The problem I'm facing right now is, there are only a few (mostly unanswered) questions regarding to WinRT panels I found on the internet. The only solutions I found were all targeting WPF and relying on IScrollInfo interface which is not available in WinRT.

I also thought of deriving from (Oriented)VirtualizingPanel, but they're all sealed or have internal constructors.

So my question is: Does anyone knows where to find a good tutorial on how to implement a custom virtualizing panel for a ListView/GridView in WinRT. Or am I doomed to write my complete whole ItemsControl implementation whith scroll handling and virtualization from scratch up? I mean it would be possible at all, but it's lot of work to do. I can't believe MS Devs think we aren't capable of writing performant virtualizing panels and therefore locking it all down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a complete answer as well.  IMO virtualization of the platform isn't "bad", but it doesn't support all types of virtualization.  E.g. scrolling supa'fast thru video frames.

Windows Phone Toolkit's primitive "LoopingSelector" has an example of how to write a "Canvas" as a virtualizing items panel. Alas, this is Silverlight and not WinRT, but it should be close - it should be only rewriting it to use Pointer instead of mouse events.

Also I'm looking at "Random access virtualization" for a possible idea.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx

Comment: continuing this path on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361856/random-access-data-virtualization-for-listview-on-windows-runtime